# Miva Merchant (Miva Script) When Making A Payment Module, How Do I Retrieve The Following Variables

Tags: variables, module, payment

- Order Total
- Billing Address
- Billing Zip
- Billing Email

I am a beginning MM developer and I am finding that proper documentation for developers with Miva Merchant is very inadequate. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured out how to get the Order Total (or Basket Total as MM refers to it as).

First, get the total and assign it to a variable like so:

```
<MvASSIGN NAME = "l.formatted_total" VALUE = "{ [ g.Module_Library_DB ].Basket_Total( g.Basket:basket_id ) }">
```

Next, put it into a hidden input like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Total" value="{ encodeentities( l.formatted_total ) }">
```

I also figured out how to get the other variables as well.

**- Zip:**

```
<MvASSIGN NAME = "l.bill_zip" VALUE = "{ g.Basket:bill_zip }">
```

**- Address:**

```
<MvASSIGN NAME = "l.bill_address" VALUE = "{ g.Basket:bill_addr1 }">
```

**- Email:**

```
<MvASSIGN NAME = "l.bill_email" VALUE = "{ g.Basket:bill_email }">
```

Then add the variables to hidden inputs:

**- Zip:**

```
<input type="hidden" name="Zip" value="{ encodeentities( l.bill_zip ) }">
```

**- Address:**

```
<input type="hidden" name="Address" value="{ encodeentities( l.bill_address ) }">
```

**- Email:**

```
<input type="hidden" name="EMail" value="{ encodeentities( l.bill_email ) }">
```